# How can I fix the error 'x' must be a numeric matrix with the command heatmap() in R?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, numeric

I know that this question has been asked and answered multiple times, but I am still stumped.

I read my CSV into R, converted it into a matrix with `as.matrix(data)`, and properly assigned the names to the columns and rows and deleted those factors. When I view my matrix, it looks proper.  I have even used `as.numeric(as.matrix(data))`. When I run the object through `is.numeric(data)` and the result was `TRUE`.

My view of the matrix:

```
> data

        JOHW           UOK161         SAUJ.y        UOK140         SHEKO.y      
AGT     "1.819354e+00" "   24.727533" "  819.32560" "1.607498e+02" "  85.094938"
ANXA13  "1.212902e+00" "    1.177502" "  485.30797" "7.442122e-01" " 111.144408"
ASAP3   "6.398060e+02" "   54.753822" " 1430.38139" "2.493111e+02" " 336.906488"
ATL1    "4.669674e+01" "   54.753822" "  288.82701" "1.309814e+02" "  27.786102"
ATP10A  "2.428837e+03" " 2591.680909" "  389.03230" "2.999175e+02" "   6.946526"
BCL2L15 "6.852899e+01" "   41.801305" "  243.63639" "1.711688e+01" "  26.049471"
BHMT    "1.212902e+00" "    5.887508" "  361.52497" "3.572219e+01" "  92.041463"
CCDC8   "3.032256e+00" "  263.171596" "  762.34613" "1.719130e+02" "   0.000000"
CHMP4C  "6.810447e+02" "  618.777064" "  369.38421" "6.489531e+02" "  85.094938"
CLDN2   "2.392450e+03" " 3095.062822" " 1609.17906" "5.313675e+02" "8497.337336"
CLIC3   "9.703219e+01" "    1.766252" " 1186.74500" "1.555404e+02" " 279.597652"
CSF2    "1.114657e+03" "   69.472591" "    0.00000" "6.668142e+02" "  98.987989"
CXCL1   "8.982149e+03" "  195.465257" "   72.69796" "2.701863e+04" "1540.392033"
CXCL8   "8.857826e+03" "  174.270229" "  715.19069" "5.974461e+04" "5925.386264"
DAPK1   "3.502862e+03" "10547.470130" "  471.55430" "2.759539e+03" "  31.259365"
DENND2A "4.427094e+01" "   88.312616" "  459.76545" "3.825251e+02" "  90.304832"
DSP     "8.854188e+01" " 8522.167461" "  695.54260" "1.677454e+03" "  45.152416"
EMX2    "0.000000e+00" "    6.476259" "  117.88858" "7.442122e-01" " 797.113803"
ETNK2   "2.910966e+02" "  382.688003" "  294.72144" "1.391677e+02" "  53.835573"
FER1L4  "1.121935e+02" "  469.823118" "  687.68336" "8.357504e+02" " 112.881040"
FLNC    "1.819354e+00" "  141.888937" "  807.53675" "2.945592e+03" " 187.556189"
GSN     "2.092257e+03" " 2320.855553" " 4743.05038" "4.105075e+03" "1033.295670"
HAGLR   "9.945800e+02" "    8.242511" "   43.22581" "5.983466e+02" " 425.474688"
HSPG2   "2.340235e+04" "11716.729160" " 2375.45481" "2.935099e+04" " 329.959962"
IGSF3   "6.301028e+02" " 3352.346910" " 1754.57497" "5.480379e+03" " 230.971973"
IL1R2   "2.480385e+02" "  161.906463" "  296.68625" "2.947080e+02" "  39.942522"
IL4I1   "2.140773e+02" "   97.732629" "   29.47214" "1.112597e+03" " 164.979981"
IL6     "8.490317e+02" "   14.130019" "   86.45162" "7.971257e+03" " 477.573629"
IRX6    "6.064512e-01" "    1.177502" "  159.14958" "3.721061e+01" "   1.736631"
KCNK1   "1.334193e+02" "  193.699005" " 1112.08223" "9.525917e+02" " 107.671145"
KCTD17  "5.003222e+02" "  184.278992" "  756.45170" "1.189251e+03" "  76.411781"
KLF2    "8.369027e+01" "  145.421441" "  196.48096" "1.175855e+02" " 866.579058"
MFSD2A  "1.006709e+02" "   77.126351" "  233.81234" "5.834624e+02" "  19.102945"
MLPH    "1.819354e+00" "   44.156308" "  115.92377" "2.000443e+03" "1430.984256"
NBL1    "4.634500e+03" " 2298.483024" " 3373.57809" "4.120703e+03" " 720.702022"
PCSK5   "4.857674e+02" " 2237.252943" " 5246.04163" "5.953698e+02" " 659.919924"
PHF2    "1.360877e+03" " 1474.820690" "  263.28449" "5.760203e+02" "   5.209894"
PLEKHF2 "7.720124e+02" "  674.119637" "  117.88858" "6.206730e+02" " 540.092359"
PRUNE2  "9.964600e+03" "  261.994095" "10258.27093" "3.731480e+03" "2823.762622"
PSG1    "7.944511e+01" "  264.937848" "   60.90910" "8.186335e+00" " 595.664563"
PSG4    "3.032256e+00" "   61.818831" "  406.71559" "3.081039e+02" "4027.248167"
RHOB    "7.871737e+02" " 8911.331723" "11099.20944" "1.444516e+03" "1839.092630"
SCARF2  "3.638707e+00" "  207.829023" "  261.31968" "1.205624e+02" "  13.893051"
SCN3A   "1.983095e+02" "    6.476259" "  475.48392" "8.930547e+01" "  86.831569"
SEMA6D  "0.000000e+00" "   42.978807" "  571.75959" "7.442122e-01" "  27.786102"
SMIM24  "3.638707e+00" "    3.532505" "  685.71855" "1.205624e+02" " 100.724620"
SMPDL3A "2.474321e+02" " 1447.149404" " 1937.30227" "2.374037e+02" " 430.684582"
SPOCK1  "6.929918e+03" " 1133.345241" "21233.69736" "2.625953e+04" "4909.456908"
SULF2   "4.851610e+00" " 2137.754062" " 5088.85687" "4.219683e+02" "1125.337133"
TPD52   "2.226889e+03" " 1012.651332" " 1035.45466" "2.391154e+03" " 192.766083"
TRHDE   "6.670963e+00" "    1.766252" "  734.83879" "1.488424e+01" "  85.094938"
TTC9    "6.185802e+01" "   64.762585" "  269.17892" "1.815878e+02" "  45.152416"
UGT1A9  "1.028541e+03" " 1622.597135" "  104.13491" "1.827785e+03" "2538.955076"
VAV3    "7.823221e+01" "  592.872030" " 4255.77759" "8.156566e+02" " 423.738056"
VWA7    "3.396127e+01" "   65.351336" "  351.70092" "3.661524e+02" "  60.782098"
WNT5A   "1.368154e+03" "  471.589370" "  373.31382" "1.780156e+03" "  67.728624"
```

When I run the heat map command:

```
heatmap(data, scale="column", main="Genomic Expression")
```

I get

```
Error in heatmap(y, scale = "column", main = "Genomic Expression") : 
  'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

Am I missing something?
...........

EDIT

```
dput(data)



>  structure(c("1.819354e+00", "1.212902e+00", "6.398060e+02",
> "4.669674e+01",  "2.428837e+03", "6.852899e+01", "1.212902e+00",
> "3.032256e+00",  "6.810447e+02", "2.392450e+03", "9.703219e+01",
> "1.114657e+03",  "8.982149e+03", "8.857826e+03", "3.502862e+03",
> "4.427094e+01",  "8.854188e+01", "0.000000e+00", "2.910966e+02",
> "1.121935e+02",  "1.819354e+00", "2.092257e+03", "9.945800e+02",
> "2.340235e+04",  "6.301028e+02", "2.480385e+02", "2.140773e+02",
> "8.490317e+02",  "6.064512e-01", "1.334193e+02", "5.003222e+02",
> "8.369027e+01",  "1.006709e+02", "1.819354e+00", "4.634500e+03",
> "4.857674e+02",  "1.360877e+03", "7.720124e+02", "9.964600e+03",
> "7.944511e+01",  "3.032256e+00", "7.871737e+02", "3.638707e+00",
> "1.983095e+02",  "0.000000e+00", "3.638707e+00", "2.474321e+02",
> "6.929918e+03",  "4.851610e+00", "2.226889e+03", "6.670963e+00",
> "6.185802e+01",  "1.028541e+03", "7.823221e+01", "3.396127e+01",
> "1.368154e+03",  "   24.727533", "    1.177502", "   54.753822", "  
> 54.753822",  " 2591.680909", "   41.801305", "    5.887508", "  263.171596",  "  618.777064", " 3095.062822", "    1.766252", "   69.472591",  "  195.465257", "  174.270229", "10547.470130", "   88.312616",  " 8522.167461", "    6.476259", "  382.688003", "  469.823118",  "  141.888937", " 2320.855553", "    8.242511", "11716.729160",  " 3352.346910", "  161.906463", "   97.732629", "  
> 14.130019",  "    1.177502", "  193.699005", "  184.278992", "  145.421441",  "   77.126351", "   44.156308", " 2298.483024", " 2237.252943",  " 1474.820690", "  674.119637", "  261.994095", "  264.937848",  "   61.818831", " 8911.331723", "  207.829023", "    6.476259",  "   42.978807", "    3.532505", " 1447.149404", " 1133.345241",  " 2137.754062", " 1012.651332", "    1.766252", "   64.762585",  " 1622.597135", "  592.872030", "   65.351336", "  471.589370",  "  819.32560", "  485.30797", " 1430.38139", "  288.82701", "  389.03230",  "  243.63639", "  361.52497", "  762.34613", "  369.38421", " 1609.17906",  " 1186.74500", "    0.00000", "   72.69796", "  715.19069", "  471.55430",  "  459.76545", "  695.54260", "  117.88858", "  294.72144", "  687.68336",  " 
> 807.53675", " 4743.05038", "   43.22581", " 2375.45481", " 1754.57497",  "  296.68625", "   29.47214", "   86.45162", "  159.14958", " 1112.08223",  "  756.45170", "  196.48096", "  233.81234", "  115.92377", " 3373.57809",  " 5246.04163", "  263.28449", "  117.88858", "10258.27093", "   60.90910",  "  406.71559", "11099.20944", "  261.31968", "  475.48392", "  571.75959",  "  685.71855", " 1937.30227", "21233.69736", " 5088.85687", " 1035.45466",  "  734.83879", "  269.17892", "  104.13491", " 4255.77759", "  351.70092",  "  373.31382", "1.607498e+02", "7.442122e-01", "2.493111e+02",  "1.309814e+02",
> "2.999175e+02", "1.711688e+01", "3.572219e+01",  "1.719130e+02",
> "6.489531e+02", "5.313675e+02", "1.555404e+02",  "6.668142e+02",
> "2.701863e+04", "5.974461e+04", "2.759539e+03",  "3.825251e+02",
> "1.677454e+03", "7.442122e-01", "1.391677e+02",  "8.357504e+02",
> "2.945592e+03", "4.105075e+03", "5.983466e+02",  "2.935099e+04",
> "5.480379e+03", "2.947080e+02", "1.112597e+03",  "7.971257e+03",
> "3.721061e+01", "9.525917e+02", "1.189251e+03",  "1.175855e+02",
> "5.834624e+02", "2.000443e+03", "4.120703e+03",  "5.953698e+02",
> "5.760203e+02", "6.206730e+02", "3.731480e+03",  "8.186335e+00",
> "3.081039e+02", "1.444516e+03", "1.205624e+02",  "8.930547e+01",
> "7.442122e-01", "1.205624e+02", "2.374037e+02",  "2.625953e+04",
> "4.219683e+02", "2.391154e+03", "1.488424e+01",  "1.815878e+02",
> "1.827785e+03", "8.156566e+02", "3.661524e+02",  "1.780156e+03", " 
> 85.094938", " 111.144408", " 336.906488",  "  27.786102", "   6.946526", "  26.049471", "  92.041463", "   0.000000",  "  85.094938", "8497.337336", " 279.597652", "  98.987989", "1540.392033",  "5925.386264", "  31.259365", "  90.304832", " 
> 45.152416", " 797.113803",  "  53.835573", " 112.881040", " 187.556189", "1033.295670", " 425.474688",  " 329.959962", " 230.971973", "  39.942522", " 164.979981", " 477.573629",  "   1.736631", " 107.671145", "  76.411781", " 866.579058", "  19.102945",  "1430.984256", " 720.702022", " 659.919924", "   5.209894", "
> 540.092359",  "2823.762622", " 595.664563", "4027.248167", "1839.092630", "  13.893051",  "  86.831569", "  27.786102", "
> 100.724620", " 430.684582", "4909.456908",  "1125.337133", " 192.766083", "  85.094938", "  45.152416", "2538.955076",  " 423.738056", "  60.782098", "  67.728624"), .Dim = c(56L, 5L ), .Dimnames = list(c("AGT", "ANXA13", "ASAP3", "ATL1", "ATP10A", 
> "BCL2L15", "BHMT", "CCDC8", "CHMP4C", "CLDN2", "CLIC3", "CSF2", 
> "CXCL1", "CXCL8", "DAPK1", "DENND2A", "DSP", "EMX2", "ETNK2", 
> "FER1L4", "FLNC", "GSN", "HAGLR", "HSPG2", "IGSF3", "IL1R2",  "IL4I1",
> "IL6", "IRX6", "KCNK1", "KCTD17", "KLF2", "MFSD2A",  "MLPH", "NBL1",
> "PCSK5", "PHF2", "PLEKHF2", "PRUNE2", "PSG1",  "PSG4", "RHOB",
> "SCARF2", "SCN3A", "SEMA6D", "SMIM24", "SMPDL3A",  "SPOCK1", "SULF2",
> "TPD52", "TRHDE", "TTC9", "UGT1A9", "VAV3",  "VWA7", "WNT5A"),
> c("JOHW", "UOK161", "SAUJ.y", "UOK140", "SHEKO.y" )))
```

Comment: Please let us see what R sees.  Type `dput(data)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: your AGT row, JOHNW column and stuff below are all quoted with "1.819354e+00", so if you dput your matrix, rather than just the data, you'll see the full structure (with row and column names), that will indicate that those quoted numbers are all character. I'm thinking if you go back to the import of the CSV with stringsAsFactors = FALSE, things might improve. But dput the matrix as an aid to our understanding.

Comment: @Emily, write up what you did as an answer. Then accept your (own) answer. This is both perfectly legitimate and responsible as it answers and hence closes a problem question, is easier for other users (new or old) to follow rather than trying to hack their way through comments, and you increase your reputation besides. It is a virtuous circle of giving back to your new community. And welcome, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using stringsAsFactors when importing my csv did the trick:

```
heatmapmatrix <- read.csv(file = 'heatmapmatrix.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
rownames(heatmapmatrix) <- heatmapmatrix[, 1]
data <- heatmapmatrix[,-1]
data <- as.matrix(data)
heatmap(data)
```